# Telling Excel VBA TextToColumns NOT to split by spaces

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am using VBA in Excel 2003.
Here is the simplest example of the problem I am having.
I want to split a string by *commas* only, into cells in the row.

In Cell A1, I have the following string:

```
A B,C
```

In VBA, if I say `Range("A1").TextToColumns Comma:=True,Space:=False`, it does what I expect.  Cell A1 is `A B` and Cell B1 is `C`

But if I have this string:

```
A B C,D
```

then if I use `Range("A1").TextToColumns Comma:=True,Space:=False`, it splits by **SPACES** anyway! Cell A1 is `A`, Cell B1 is `B`, Cell C1 is `C,D` (?!)

Why is `TextToColumns` automatically splitting by spaces when there are more than one space, even when I *explicitly* tell it not to? Is this a known bug?
Is there a workaround, other than manually parsing the strings into columns myself?

Comment: This question is interesting because it exposes a likely Excel-VBA bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to explicitly set `DataType` to `xlDelimited`, else Excel assumes you data is arranged in fixed-width columns, and Excel's initial guess at how wide those columns are is where the spaces are -- ignoring whatever delimiters you choose in the argument list.

Try the following and you will see that it reproduces your results:

```
Range("A1").TextToColumns DataType:=xlFixedWidth
```

which gives the same results as omitting the `DataType` argument:

```
Range("A1").TextToColumns
```

Note that the Excel documentation is erroneous in this respect: it says `xlDelimited` is the default, but clearly `xlFixedWidth` is the default in reality.

So, long story short, what you want instead is this:

```
Range("A1").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True, Space:=False
```

**EDIT** It looks like a little more than the Excel documentation may be wrong. This actually smells like a bug in Excel-VBA. See discussion in the comments below.

Comment: Aha, xlDelimited is what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: That certainly fixes it, but I don't think it's the whole story.  If I omit DataType and *don't* used named arguments, I get the expected behavior.  Also, help says re Comma "...True to have DataType be xlDelimited and to have the comma be a delimiter...", which makes me think setting comma to True would force xlDelimited.  Clearly that's not the case.  It seems that named arguments sets a default that's different than when not using named arguments.  Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Bug indeed, and I actually think it's even worse and weirder than what you describe. See my 2nd comment to JP's answer below. The take-home message is probably to used named arguments (non-named arguments clearly lead to unpredictable behaviour) and never assume that the defaults will work, so specify as many named arguments as necessary to make your tests work properly.

Comment: After some more testing, the only parameter I actually need (at least for my purposes) is DataType:=xlDelimited . Comma and Space do not need to be explicitly set anymore. Perfect!

Comment: That's nice. But to keep your code readable, I would advise to set things explicitly, so the next person reading your code (maybe you next year) knows exactly what the intent is.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ConsecutiveDelimiter` to `True`:

`Range("A1").TextToColumns ,,,True,,,True,False`

Comment: But this doesn't make any difference... Did you test before posting?!

Comment: My bad, fixing code now. Yes I did test it, but I didn't use named parameters. My attempt to convert it to named parameters obviously failed.

Comment: Hm, this highly unreadable statement does "work", even though there is no rational explanation for why -- and converting the argument list to named parameters makes it *not* work... Smells like an Excel bug, and not like a recommendable answer. P.S. downvote isn't mine even though I was initially tempted.

Comment: That's probably why it failed when I posted it using named parameters. Can't explain it. +1 for your answer, it's better anyway.

Comment: And thanks to whomever dinged me for what is ultimately a problem with Excel, not my code.

Comment: IMHO that was a fair shot. Your original answer didn't work and there was no reason to think it should!