# How many columns were created by TextToColumns?

Tags: excel, vba

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331245/telling-excel-vba-texttocolumns-not-to-split-by-spaces) ended up being more interesting than I thought it would be, and I have solved the direct issue for my purposes.

But now I have a question for which the answer should be simple, but I can't find it.

After TextToColumns has done its thing, how can I figure out **how many columns** were created?
The number of columns in my results are variable, and it's not guaranteed that there's whitespace after the end of the split.

It would be great if the TextToColumns function returned the number of columns it created, but that doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to just count the commas before splitting; there are situations of commas inside quotes, for example, which TextToColumns seems to handle just fine. If I was going to have to count character-by-character, then I might as well write my own split function.

(The reason I need this is so I can offer the option to transpose the results)

Thanks.

Comment: If there's no "clear" area to the right of the values being split (allowing HRgiger's suggested solution) then I think you're stuck with checking each cell's value to determine the max number of columns.  Or - with screenupdating off - move the data to be split to a new sheet and split it there, and use the `usedrange.columns.count` approach.

Comment: Or you could run the split on a copy of the worksheet, compare the original to working sheet to get the new size, then destroy the working sheet and resume your code with your tranpose size known.

Comment: The answer is in the comments. At least if you don't want to assume that the data to split is the only (or last) column in the sheet.

Comment: @GlennFromIowa thanks for your contribution; I don't even remember what I was working on when I asked this question 7 years ago but I'm pretty sure I figured it out.

Comment: Yeah, the *comment answer* helped me and I was looking for an answer to upvote. It's a shame when people don't turn their comments into answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with UsedRange. Please see below example:

```
Sub check()
Dim before As Integer
Dim after As Integer
before = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
MsgBox before
Range("A1").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=True
after = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
MsgBox after
MsgBox after - before
End Sub
```

Comment: There's also a chance that my TtC call will be overwriting cells that already had data in them. So I don't think it would work to simply count how many columns are being used.

Comment: @Josh I guess you go add a sheet and do the above but setting the destination to the new sheet and then find out the used range. Of course it would be up to you to either copy the data or do another Text to Column

Comment: I'm not exactly happy with this solution, but it sounds like doing this on a hidden sheet, or writing my own split, is my only option.